# Behavior of 1.2 ∈ Rationals changes in v9?

Tags: number-theory, version-9, compatibility, data-types

A friend of mine using version 9 recently showed me this:

[image]

It's strange because in version 8.0.4 `1.2 ∈ Rationals` does return `False`:

[image]

I checked the online document of [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Element.html) and [`Rationals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationals.html), no modification is mentioned. So it's a silent changing, or a bug?

Comment: I just want to clarify that `Element` does not check *data types* (a programming concept).  It checks whether a value is mathematically rational.  It makes sense that it is unknown whether an *inexact* number is rational or not.  Inexact means that it is known only to a finite precision.  So I'd call that v8 behaviour a bug and the v9 behaviour correct.

Comment: I agree with @Szabolcs. The V.9 behavior is more consistent with the underlying concept of "approximate number".

Comment: Also, the Mathematica 8 result is arguably wrong because a floating point number is always a rational number of the form $m/2^n$.

Comment: @celtschk well, arguably. But Szabolcs's point that *Mathematica*'s numerical model treats floating point numbers as being distributions on the reals rather than exact rationals would tend to argue against that interpretation in this case. If you want to treat any FP number as a rational, you can always use `SetPrecision` on it. (Of course, things get a bit fuzzy when we start to consider comparisons between these distributions...)

Answer (score 3):

Just to illustrate Szabolcs's comments, see the behaviour of:

```
Element[1., Rationals]
```

This returns the input.

versus

```
Element[Rationalize[1.],Rationals]
```

This returns True (as expected)

and

```
Element[Rationalize[1.2],Rationals]
```

This returns True.

Comment: It would be better if you were to show the results rather than asking people copy your code and do the evaluation. Why make them repeat the work you have already done?

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for appropriate criticism. I have edited answer to be more useful.

Comment: Hmm……I'm afraid that the second example isn't proper. Consider `Element[IntegerPart[Sqrt[2]], Rationals]`.

Comment: @xzczd yes I guess I was just trying to contrast 1. with 1 as per szabolcs comment...so I have adjusted to `Rationaloze` which will address your point

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 return `False` for `1.2 ∈ Rationals`:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

... while the latest available versions don't:

[image: screesnhot3]

[Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) explained this change in the comments:

> I just want to clarify that `Element` does not check *data types* (a
> programming concept). It checks whether a value is mathematically
> rational. It makes sense that it is unknown whether an *inexact* number
> is rational or not. Inexact means that it is known only to a finite
> precision. So I'd call that v8 behaviour a bug and the v9 behaviour
> correct. – [Szabolcs May 3, 2014 at 13:43](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47218/behavior-of-1-2-%E2%88%88-rationals-changes-in-v9#comment140074_47218)

This explanation is fully consistent with the Documentation:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screesnhot4]